# node.js post request handle with busboy and after multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm trying to use busboy(or multiparty) and multer to parse my request. Firstly, I receive my request thanks to busboy and I will create some folder and update my database. Secondly, when I call multer and nothing happens. My request is not parse. and multer is not call.
I don't understand why.

This is my class DBAccess.js:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var DBManager = require('./DBManager');
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

function beforeMulter(req,res,next) {
    var meshName='';
    var type='';
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
        file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });
    });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
        if(fieldname== 'name') {
            meshName = val;
        }
        if(fieldname == 'type') {
            type=val;
            req.params.id=1;
        }
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Done parsing form!');
        next();
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
}

function uploadManager(req,res,next) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(req.originalUrl);
        next();
    });
}

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("In destination");
        console.log("ID : " + req.params.id);
        DBManager.initialize();
        var path=DBManager.createDestination(req.params.id,req.originalUrl);
        cb(null, path);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("In filename");
        var extension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
        cb(null, req.body.name.split(".")[0] + Date.now() + "." + extension);
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('file');

module.exports.uploadManager = uploadManager;
module.exports.upload = upload;
module.exports.beforeMulter = beforeMulter;
```

And my router.js:

```
var db_access                   = require('../DBAccess');
var db_manager                  = require('../DBManager');
var express                     = require('express');
var router                      = express.Router();


router.post('/create',
db_access.beforeMulter,
db_access.uploadManager,
function(req, res,next){
    //console.log(req.body)
    //console.log(req.files)
    res.status(204).end()
});

module.exports = router;
```

Would anyone know what this error could be caused by? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`multer` already *uses* Busboy under the hood, so you typically do not need to use both unless you need more fine grained access that `multer` does not currently provide.

The problem is that `busboy` has already read (and parsed) all of the request data so there is nothing left for `multer` to read/parse. This problem is not specific to these two particular modules though. Any two middleware that reads any/all of the request data will have this issue. So the solution is to choose one or the other.